# Any way to design a view/read only form

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am new to web development and vuetify. I was going thro' the Form templates. My question is, assume we are creating a profile form with usual fields like TextField, Select, Option etc. This will be like editable format. But once i submit and reopen/refresh, i would like to see the same form in the same structure but in a read only view. How can i do it in Vuetify, is there any template like such that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear from your question if you want to be able to edit the form *once* and after that you would want it to be read-only.
If so, you would need some "storage" functionality in order to keep track seen forms (you could do this with localStorage if you dont want to involve a backend).

After you've decided on that you can set an input field to `disabled` which would disable your field from being editable.

```
<input type="text" value="my read only field" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Then dependent on how you implement it, it'd be something along the lines of

```
<input type="text" value="my read only field" v-bind:disabled="formIsSeen"
```

Comment: Yes. That's the idea i need. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for Vuetify, in your HTML, you need to:

- Display the form
- Set the property of the field to disabled
- Set the value of each field to the originally inputted data.

For example:

```
 <v-text-field
        name="input-3"
        label="Label Text"
        value="Data from the original submission"
        disabled
        single-line
      ></v-text-field>
```